# What is the relation between connections on principal bundles and connections on vector bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I'm reading Kobayashi / Nomizu 's  vol. I. I am reading about connections in principal G-bundles. After that chapter there's a chapter on (linear) connections on Vector bundles. Since we can associate to every principal bundle a vector bundle (via the twisted product) and to every vector bundle a principal vector bundle, i was wondering if we can do this:

Given a connection on a principal bundle, define an associated connection in the associated vector bundle, and conversely given a (linear) connection in a vector bundle, define an associated connection in the associated principal bundle.

If anyone knows how to do this or can point me to a book that has this done, I'll be very grateful.

I tried to do it by myself but if there's an obvious way to do it I am missing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $P$ be a principal $G$-bundle, $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ a finite dimensional representation of $G$, $E = P \times_G V$ the associated vector bundle. To any principal connection $\Phi$ on $P$ is associated an induced linear connection $\bar \Phi$ on $E$. Conversely, any linear connection on a vector bundle $E$ is induced from a unique principal connection on the linear frame bundle $GL(\mathbb R^n, E)$ of $E$.

You can find all the details here: [Topics in Differential Geometry - P. W. Michor](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf&rct=j&q=michor%20differential&ei=xDoIToalIM2q-AaLq5zRDQ&usg=AFQjCNFR22uxHk5U3nOhtySE1ZEb-nEzyA&cad=rja).

Comment: I found this reference easier to follow. Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

Given a faithful representation $V$ of a group $G$, the associated bundle construction is an equivalence of categories between principal bundles on a locally ringed space $M$ with fiber $G$ and vector bundles on $M$ with fiber $V$.  This is more or less in Steenrod's *Topology of fiber bundles*.

Given a principal bundle $P$ and a corresponding vector bundle $W$, there is a bijection between connections on $P$ and connections on $W$.  One way of making this clear is to use [Grothendieck's definition of connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_connection): Let $\Delta: M \to M \times M$ be the diagonal on the base manifold, and let $I$ be the sheaf of ideals that defines $\Delta(M)$ as a submanifold of $M \times M$.  The locally ringed space $M^{(1)}$defined by $I^2$ is the first-order neighborhood of the diagonal, and the inclusion into $M \times M$ induces maps $p_1, p_2: M^{(1)} \to M$.  A connection on $P$ is an isomorphism $p_1^* P \to p_2^* P$, and a connection on $W$ is an isomorphism $p_1^* W \to p_2^* W$.  Their correspondence follows from the equivalence in the first paragraph.

Possible references include Grothendieck's 1970 ICM lecture, available at [the ICM proceedings site](https://www.mathunion.org/icm/proceedings), and Berthelot's thesis (Springer Lecture Notes 407).

Comment: ICM proceedings link is broken..

Comment: Thanks.  I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much :)