# Induced Connection on Vector Bundle from Principal Bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

In "The Topology of Fiber Bundles" by Cohen [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/fiber.pdf), in page 39, he says:

> We end this section by observing that if $P$ is a principal $G$ - bundle with a connection $\omega_A$, then any representation of $G$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ induces a connection on the corresponding vector bundle:
>   $P \times_G V \to M.$

I supposed it is a kind of trivial. I was wondering how a *connection on Principal Bundle* easily induces a *linear* connection on the vector bundle $P\times_G V\to M$. I tried to induce a kind of connection on the vector bundle but I could not show it is either linear or is from zero forms to one forms and obeys Leibniz's rule.

P.S. I read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47888/what-is-the-relation-between-connections-on-principal-bundles-and-connections-on) but I could not find my answer in the references there.

Comment: Can you write down here **how you have tried** to associate a connection on a fiber bundle $P\times_GV\rightarrow M$  given a connection on the principal bundle? Btw, what is your definition of connection on Principal bundle?